# Fonts align to bottom of inline list

Tags: css, fonts, zurb-foundation, font-awesome

i have a simple inline list as below :

```
         <ul class="list-inline">
            <li>
            <p>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                  <i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
              </span>
             </p>
            </li>
            <li>

               <h6>May - june</h6>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

css

```
.list-inline {
    margin-left: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.list-inline>li {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0.3rem;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

however the output is has below image : any solution for this , am using foundation6 framework ,
[image: selection_008]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to understand your problem, since the image doesn't seem to correspond with your html, but there is one thing in your code that cannot work as you describe it:

You put a `<h6>` tag inside a `<li>` tag. Header tags like `<h6>` are by default block elements, so if you put this into an inline-set  `<li>` tag, it will mess up the inline alignment.

Also the `<p>` tag in the first `<li>` is a block element - same thing...

Comment: ok thanks for the tip mate , so what do you suggest to use insted of `p` or `h5`

Comment: classes on the `li` tags, with the properties that you want